# Heroku not detecting composer.lock file

Tags: heroku, composer-php

I want to make a deploy but I can't. I don't know why.

I ran the `composer install` command to generate the lock file...

Error log:

```
 ERROR: No 'composer.lock' found!

 A 'composer.lock' file was not found in your project, but there
 is a 'composer.json' file with dependencies inside 'require'.

 The lock file is required in order to guarantee reliable and
 reproducible installation of dependencies across platforms and
 deploys. You must follow the Composer best practice of having
 your lock file under version control in order to deploy. The
 lock file must not be in your '.gitignore'.
```

My `.gitignore`:

```
/vendor
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
```

I committed the file.
My last 3 commits (from `git log --oneline`):

```
19cb5e3 (HEAD -> demo) env update
2ce2333 added composer.lock
285922a Demo
```

Comment: Does `git log composer.lock` show you commits, or return without printing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete your vendor folder + composer.lock and then try to run composer install.